# SectionList get section index in renderSectionHeader

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

```
<SectionList
  sections={[{ data: [1, 2] }, { data: [3, 4] }]}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => ...}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section, index }, i) => {
    console.log(index, i); // both undefined
  }}
/>
```

I want to get the index of the section in `renderSectionHeader`.
Eg. `index` should be 0 when `section.data` is `[1, 2]` and 1 when `section.data` is `[3, 4]`.

How can I accomplish this apart from adding the index to the `sections` data?

Answer (score 36):

There's no section index of renderSectionHeader in SectionList of react native but you can add an index prop to your sections like this

```
 sections={[{ data: [1, 2], index:0 }, { data: [3, 4], index:1 }]}
```

and then access the index in renderSectionHeader like this

```
 renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
     console.log(section.index); 
 }}
```

Comment: You saved my day!! Custom index was needed !! Thank you.

Comment: This is very useful to include any data for a section.

Comment: what if our sections are dynamic and we cant hardcode the index?

Comment: I agree with @PulkitSharma, what if our data is dynamic? It;s not gonna work. It's not a good solution.

Comment: If you need to add an index dynamically, just map it in. `<SectionList sections={sections.map((section, index) => ({ ...section, index }))} />`

Comment: The above comment helped me a lot as I have a nested array and needed an index of the header which I selected. Thank you for the above solution.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is late but maybe It helps someone. A better way is to get the index of your section from the array you are passing to the SectionList component.
    For example supposing you have `dataList` as array which is passed to sections `sections={dataList}`, then you can get the index as following:

```
renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
    const index = dataList.indexOf(section)
    // Here you have the index
    return <View />
}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not a good solution since you are using `indexOf ` and that means an extra search which is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since my array has different structure, I needed to transform it first to be `title` and `data` but with added `index`:

```
const transformedData = data.reduce((r: any, s: any, i: number) => {
    r.push({
        index: i, // newly added, to be used later
        title: s.month,
        data: s.summaries
    });
    return r;
}, []);
```

`reduce()`'s 3rd parameter is an index, so I extracted that and explicitly created an `index` in my new object when I pushed it in the transformedData array.

```
<SectionList
    sections={transformedData}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `report-${index}`}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return <Cell summary={item} idx={index} />;
    }}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
    renderSectionHeader={({section: {index, title}}) => (
        <BodySubText style={{marginTop: index === 0 ? 16 : 24, backgroundColor: 'red'}} text={title} />
    )}
/>
```

Now in the `renderSectionHeader` props, I can now use extract `index` from the destructured `section`.